# Total memory system of iphone not matching with real memory size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory, memory-management

I've got some problem to get free, inactive, used and wire memory system on iphone using code (the purpose is to display these informations to the user).

I have found on other thread code that give all memory details :

```
int mib[6];
mib[0] = CTL_HW;
mib[1] = HW_PAGESIZE;

int pagesize;
size_t length;
length = sizeof (pagesize);
if (sysctl (mib, 2, &pagesize, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "getting page size");
}

mach_msg_type_number_t count = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;

vm_statistics_data_t vmstat;
if (host_statistics (mach_host_self (), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t) &vmstat, &count) != KERN_SUCCESS)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Failed to get VM statistics.");
}

double unit = 1024 * 1024;

NSLog(@"Free : %f , inactive : %f, active : %f, wired : %f",vmstat.free_count * pagesize / unit,vmstat.inactive_count * pagesize / unit,vmstat.active_count * pagesize / unit,vmstat.wire_count * pagesize / unit);
```

But the result is very strange :

```
Free : 344.687500 , inactive : 359.593750, active : 1383.843750, wired : 842.578125
```

I'm currently testing on iphone 5s, which is known to have only 1024 Mb of RAM. 
So if someone has an idea of how to get real informations about memory that would be great :D

Thanks!
Romain

Comment: "which is known to have only 1024 Mb of RAM" But it's a virtual memory system, isn't it? So the physical size of the RAM is irrelevant. - Your code is giving you exactly the information you asked for, so what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, thats great! I didn't know such thing... So I guess if i take the percent of these informations, i can get the physical amount of memory? btw, If i've misunderstood difference between physical and virtual memory, that doesn't deserve a down vote ! Other people can have same difficulties, that is the purpose of this website, isn't it?

Comment: ok, with "physical" add to my research I found many solutions, for exemple : http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.in/2009/01/source-code-get-hardware-info-of-iphone.html . Thanks !